# How to use NSFetchResultsController?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am developing an application in which I am using `NSFetchedResultsController`.

I have read somewhere in some tutorial that after using `NSFetchedResultsController` and setting it's batch size to some value will fetch only up to that value in your table view.

Is it so? Because, when I implemented it, I did not see any difference between using `NSFetchedResultsController` and not using it.

Comment: FetchedResultsControllers are used to seamlessly interact between CoreData and a UITableView. This means you can edit, delete, move etc values in the table and CoreData will reflect those changes. It's possible to display information from CoreData in a table without NSFetchedResultsController, though you will probably run in to bugs.

Comment: Get it...But what i asked is can I see any new thing after using NSFetchedResultsController like what i read ,only upto batch size number of rows will be displayed and after scrolling more rows will be displayed ,if so,kindly guide or can you come to chat(provide me link if so)

Comment: The batch size doesn't limit the total number of rows that will ever be fetched, it limits the number fetched *at one time*. It'll automatically fetch more as needed when you scroll, *but only in increments of the batch size*. That way, if you have a 10,000 row database, you don't have to wait to fetch all of them, so your app will be much more responsive and use less memory.

Comment: If you want to just limit the number of rows fetched, see [`setFetchLimit`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchRequest/setFetchLimit:) instead.